# Cron Bundle fail run bin/console on symfony 4

Tags: symfony, symfony4

I'm trying to run a command through a cron job in a Symfony 4 app.

I have created my command and it run success when I run manually from the console (from my symfony root directory)

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\MY-PROJECT>php bin/console MY-COMMAND /*It works fine*/
```

I installed CronBundle (https://packagist.org/packages/cron/cron-bundle) and I registered a cron job from the console:

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\MY-PROJECT>php bin/console cron:create
```

The cron job was successfully create in the database, and I try to run:

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\MY-PROJECT>php bin/console cron:run"
time: 0.15687298774719
```

The cron job seems to run but it doesn't do anything (but the console show the time elapsed). The cron_report database table report the error => "Could not open input file: bin/console"

It seems that the cron bundle run the command from a different directory than the one I use when I run the command manually (the root directory of the project).

I tried to run from the console "php bin/console cron:start", but a error message is thrown => "This command needs the pcntl extension to run." I'm running xampp on windows

Answer (score 1):

The PHP pcntl extension does [not run on Windows](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pcntl.installation.php).